# String replacement with iterator

Tags: command-line, bash, text-processing

I have a file with a character I would like to replace, but I also want to have each instance of the character(s) to be replaced, be iterated with a number inside the sting replacement.

SomeFile.txt

```
[H
A
[H
B
[H
C
```

I want to replace "[H" with "`</pre></div><div id=cat$n><pre>`" where $n is an interator for the number of replacements. So the first replacement would be 1, 2, 3, 4, n++ and so on.

Is there a way to to do this with `sed`?

Comment: It can be done with `sed` using a loop, but do you absolutely need `sed`? Perl would suit to this problem better.

Comment: I'm just looking for a solution.  Im not biased, but i dont know how to solve it with perl either.

Comment: My answer turned out to be almost identical to choroba's, so here's a slight variation (which does exactly the same thing): `perl -pe 's/^\[H$/"<\/pre><\/div><div id=cat".++$n."><pre>"/e' file`.

Comment: @j0h may I ask just for a small clarification ? You want to count number of replacements, right ? i.e. , you want to know how many times that string was replaced, correct ?

Comment: I only care that the nth number is in the string that is in the replacement. I actualy know it needs to happen 3413 times.  I think I found that with `cat filename | grep "\[H" | wc -l`  Im not saying it wouldnt be useful, but I already have that info.  Heres what the file was editing:
http://nanocluster.umeche.maine.edu/ascii/star/starWarz.html

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Perl to the rescue!

```
perl -pe 'BEGIN { $n = 1 } s%\[H%</pre></div><div id=cat$n><pre>% && $n++' filename
```

- `-p` reads the input line by line and prints whatever the code does with it
- `BEGIN { ... }` is run before the program is entered
- `s%pattern%replacement%` replaces `pattern` with `replacement`.
- `\[` needs a backslash, because `[` is special in regular expressions
- `&& $n++` If the substitution is successful, it returns true, so the next command is run: and it increments the counter `$n`.

Answer (score 4):

Another awk way, treating `[H` as the record separator:

```
awk -v RS='\\[H' 'NR>1{printf "</pre></div><div id=cat%d><pre>",NR-1}1'
```

All but the first record will have `[H` before it, so, for these records, I print a `</pre></div><div id=catN><pre>`, where `N = NR - 1` (`NR` being the record number) before the record itself.

```
$ awk -v RS='\\[H' 'NR>1{printf "</pre></div><div id=cat%d><pre>",NR-1}1' foo.txt

</pre></div><div id=cat1><pre>
A

</pre></div><div id=cat2><pre>
B

</pre></div><div id=cat3><pre>
C
```

WIth GNU awk, you can use the new inplace modification module:

```
gawk -i inplace  -v RS='\\[H' 'NR>1{printf "</pre></div><div id=cat%d><pre>",NR-1}1' foo.txt
```

This is similar to `sed -i`.

Answer (score 2):

`AWK` version. Notice how `[` is escaped and how quotes are organized to allow `counter` variable to expand in `"</pre></div><div id=cat"counter"><pre>"` :

```
$ awk '{ if ( $0~/\[H/ ){\                                                     
>    counter++; sub(/\[H/,"</pre></div><div id=cat"counter"><pre>")\           
> }; print }' test_input.txt                                                   
</pre></div><div id=cat1><pre>
A
</pre></div><div id=cat2><pre>
B
</pre></div><div id=cat3><pre>
C
</pre></div><div id=cat4><pre>
```

Unless you are using `gawk`, use `gawk '...' input_file.txt > /tmp/tmp.txt && mv /tmp/tmp.txt input_file.txt` approach to replace original file with edited version

**Addition**

As muru have suggested, the code can be simplified to

```
awk '/\[H/{counter++; sub(/\[H/,"</pre></div><div id=cat"counter"><pre>")}1' test_input.txt
```

Comment: `{ if ($0 ~/\[H/{...} }` is somewhat verbose. I think your expression boils down to : `awk '/\[H/{counter++, sub(...)}1'`.

Comment: @muru I get dual lines if I write it as `awk '/\[H/;1' test_input.txt`

Comment: Of course you will. Note that I elided only the `sub` function in my comment. The `print` was ommitted. If you want me to be verbose: `awk '/\[H/{counter++, sub(/\[H/,"</pre></div><div id=cat"counter"><pre>")}1'`

Comment: I could use `awk '/\[H/ {print $0};!/\[H/' test_input.txt   ` form though